# Assign Arguments to viewDidLoad function

Tags: swift4, xcode9

Can I assign arguments to the override fun viewDidLoad() ? I want to send String variable from another function to the viewDidLoad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No `viewDidLoad()` is a built in function that fires when the view has loaded.

You can save it in a global or data, or pass it with a **notification**, maybe even to a custom function rather ...etc

Comment: The problem I have is that I'm trying to print array in a tableview and have an empty array as global, but when I'm trying to fill the array with values from other function when I'm going to print in the tableView function it's not printing anything

Comment: By definition, if its a global and you store something in it, it should still have that data when you access it from any other class.